# How many TSI I am allowed to submit?

Tags: ios-appstore

I bought an Apple Developer Program. I submitted one of my app, and they rejected. They advised me:

*If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resource, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:*

How many times I can ask TSI question? Is it any limit?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I believe two tickets came with the program. You may purchase more. You might want to first investigate by yourself why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How many TSIs are included with my Developer Program?**
>
> - iOS Developer Program, iOS Developer Enterprise Program, and Mac Developer Program Included with each enrollment are two (2) Technical
>     Support Incidents per membership year. Additional TSIs are available
>     for purchase.
> - Safari Developer Program. TSIs are available for purchase in either a 2-Pack for $99 USD or
>     5-Pack for $249 USD. Safari Developer Program members may purchase
>     TSIs in Member Center under the Programs & Add-ons tab.
> - MFi Program. Included with each enrollment are eight (8) Technical Support
>     Incidents per membership year.

Source: [Requesting Developer Technical Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/) (you need a developer account to access).